# Displaying different images form drawable without switching activities

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view, android-drawable

[image: Buttons on another Layout and images that will be open on buttons click will be open in another layout]

As shown in the image each button click have different image, and I don't want to make different activities for view1, view2, view3 and view4 to show images:

[image]

**Question:**

I am new in Android app development. I want to display different images from drawable on different button click without switching activity for each button! Please help me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You definitely do not want to have to switch activities to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_main.xml (or how did you call it) just put id for layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainView" <!--this id-->
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

then make a field in your activity

```
Layout layout;
```

then put in onCreate():

```
layout = (Layout) findViewById (R.id.mainView);
```

then in your onClick's of your buttons you can change background using:

```
layout.setBackground(Drawable drawable);
```

instead of "Layout" you can use your kind of layout. In my case it's "RelativeLayout"

EDIT: according to your last edit, if you want to hide buttons on show the images. You can use Fragments:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

or you can hide buttons in your onClicks using

```
yourButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and then override the method onBackPressed() in your activity like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//for each button
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Of course you need to set fields for your buttons and initiate them in onCreate() like Layout above. In both cases you will see the buttons again if you press "Back".

Comment: Also you could just do one Activity for showing the image and pass the drawable id to it in the Intent

Comment: Alexandr plz tel me m i right    1)I need to add 2 layouts? and one main java acticity  2) code for layout that you give above put in layout2?

Comment: No, you have only one layout with buttons within. You just add id for your layout. Then you just change background of layout and hide buttons.

Comment: @Hareem Waqas: If you find my answer helpful, it would be nice from you to set my answer as helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent, setOnClickListener for your button:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
        case id == R.id.buttonView1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ShowImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("image", R.drawable.image1);
            startActivities(intent);
        case id == R.id.buttonView2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ShowImage.class);
            intent2.putExtra("image", R.drawable.image2);
            startActivities(intent2);
        }
    }
```

And in ShowImage activity get image id resource:

```
int image = getIntent().getIntExtra("image", R.drawable.default_image);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setImageResource(image);
```

In layout of ShowImage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```